# Deserialize an entity with a relationship with Symfony Serializer Component

Tags: json, doctrine-orm, deserialization, symfony

I'm trying to deserialize an entity with a relationship using the symfony serializer component. This is my entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Document
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="document")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DocumentRepository")
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Genre", inversedBy="documents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_genre", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    //getters and setters down here
    ...
}
```

And the **Genre entity**:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Genre
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="genre")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GenreRepository")
 */
class Genre
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Document", mappedBy="genre")
     */
    private $documents;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->documents= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //getters and setters down here
    ....
}
```

In my **controller action** right now I'm trying this:

```
$encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$document = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'AppBundle\Entity\Document', 'json');
```

And my **json data**:

```
{"name": "My document", "genre": {"id": 1, "name": "My genre"}}
```

But I got the next **error**:

> Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Genre", "array" given (500
>   Internal Server Error)

Is possible to deserialize a json request with an entity with relations inside?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: I don't know if Sf Serializer handles nested deserialisation (may be yes). But you can also try JMSSerializerBundle (which is known to have more features).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and no. First, you shouldn't re-create a new instance of the serializer in your controller but use the `serializer` service instead.

Second, no it's not possible out of the box with Symfony serializer. We are doing it in https://api-platform.com/ but there is a bit of magic there. That said, a PR has been made to support it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/19277

Comment: thanks, good answer. The PR was merged some days ago so in recent version this should be supported i suppose.

Comment: I am curious if you find the solution; i'm facing the same problem. Has the recent version supported this?

Comment: on dev-master. It will likely be only starting 3.2 I'm afraid.

Comment: OK, thanx Théo! Can you merge the edited files from the pull request in 3.1? I see there are 6 files edited..? I'm gonna give it a try, will let you know if it works.

Comment: You can try, but as it's a new feature it should land in 3.2 not 3.1 (Symfony is semver)

Comment: I eventually fixed my issue (i'm using SF2.8, but it's also possible with 3.1 i guess). But my goal was to use the JSON in an edit form. So i don't know if you trying to achieve the same as me? If you like i can post you my code.

Comment: @LexHartman Post a link to it anyway. Other people like myself are running into this same problem.

Comment: i will post it later!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is working on this in '18. I've managed to get this working using two different approaches.

The associated entities I'm working with.

```
class Category
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=45, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
}

class Item
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="uuid", length=36, unique=true)
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;
}
```

**Method 1: Using Form Classes**

```
#ItemType.php
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Item;

class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Item::class,
        ));
    }
}

#ItemController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotEncodableValueException;
use App\Entity\Item;
use App\Form\ItemType;

class ItemController extends BaseEntityController
{
    protected $entityClass = Item::class;

    /**
     * @Route("/items", methods="POST")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $item = new Item();
        $form = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $item);
        $decoded = $this->get('serializer')->decode($data, 'json');
        $form->submit($decoded);

        $object = $form->getData();

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($object);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->generateDataResponse("response text", 201);
    }
}
```

**Method 2: A Custom Normalizer**

The PropertyInfo Component needs to be enabled.

```
#/config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    property_info:
        enabled: true
```

Register the custom normalizer.

```
#/config/services.yaml
services:
    entity_normalizer:
        class: App\SupportClasses\EntityNormalizer
        public: false
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

The custom normalizer.

```
#EntityNormalizer.php
namespace App\SupportClasses;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\PropertyTypeExtractorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;


class EntityNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer
{
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        ?ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory = null,
        ?NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null,
        ?PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null,
        ?PropertyTypeExtractorInterface $propertyTypeExtractor = null
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

        parent::__construct($classMetadataFactory, $nameConverter, $propertyAccessor, $propertyTypeExtractor);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return (strpos($type, 'App\\Entity\\') === 0) && 
        (is_numeric($data) || is_string($data) || (is_array($data) && isset($data['id'])));
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->entityManager->find($class, $data);
    }
}
```

Our controller's create action.

```
#ItemController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotEncodableValueException;
use App\Entity\Item;
use App\Form\ItemType;

class ItemController extends BaseEntityController
{
    protected $entityClass = Item::class;

    /**
     * @Route("/items", methods="POST")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $object = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, $this->entityClass, 'json');

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($object);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->generateDataResponse('response text', 201);
    }
}
```

This has worked for me. I received inspiration from:
https://medium.com/@maartendeboer/using-the-symfony-serializer-with-doctrine-relations-69ecb17e6ebd

I modified the normalizer to allow me to send the category as a child json object which is converted to a child array when the data is decoded from json. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: I've used your modification for `supportsDenormalization()`, but I it took me a while to understand why it wasn't working for me, it looks for the classname to be in "App" and not "AppBundle", once that changed, it worked great

Comment: @Gimsly are you sure about `denormalize()` method inside your custom normalizer class? **Firstly.** You use `$data` like entitiy identifier, but your normalizer can get `['id' => 1, 'someField' => 'someValue']` as `$data` and Doctrine's `find()` method doesn't expect this array as it's second argument. **Secondly.** Even if you change `denormalize()` method to extract id in case if `$data` is an array, you can't simply return entity from DB as result of `denormalize()`. In this case you'll just lost all changes to entity's fields which come inside original `$data`, don't you?

Comment: I would advise against extending the `ObjectNormalizer`. By doing that, you are creating another `ObjectNormalizer` that will apply a generic array denormalization on all objects and has higher priority then the default normalizers, which can cause problems with specific objects like `DateTime`s.
If you're not going to override the normalization part, simply make your `EntityNormalizer` (which is really just a _de_normalizer) implement `DenormalizerInterface`. That's all you need, and this way it won't interfere with the other normalizers.

Answer (score 3):

It works now.You have to enable property_info in config.yml:

```
  framework:
            property_info:
                    enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this issue nowadays.
I created a solution based on @Gimsly answer. My solution uses Symfony 5.3 and also adds a custom `Denormalizer` to handle the loading of Doctrine Entities. It would additionally allow to update related existing entities by calling the `ObjectNormalizer::denormalize` with the `OBJECT_TO_POPULATE` context. If an update of the existing related object should then be allowed or not can be configured via the Serializer groups configuration.

```
namespace App\Serializer;

use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\BadMethodCallException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareDenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class DoctrineEntityDenormalizer implements ContextAwareDenormalizerInterface
{
    use DenormalizerAwareTrait;

    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $denormalizer, ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->setDenormalizer($denormalizer);
        $this->setDoctrine($doctrine);
    }

    public function denormalize($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if (null === $this->denormalizer) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Please set a denormalizer before calling denormalize()!');
        }
        $repository = $this->getRepository($type);
        if (!$repository instanceof ObjectRepository) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('No repository found for given type, '.$type.'.');
        }
        $entity = null;
        if (is_numeric($data) || is_string($data)) {
            $entity = $repository->find($data);
        } elseif (is_array($data) && isset($data['id'])) {
            $entity = $repository->find($data['id']);
        }
        if (is_null($entity)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('No Entity found for given id of type, '.$type.'.');
        }
        // Denormalize into the found entity with given data by using the default ObjectNormalizer
        $tmpContext = array_merge($context, [
            AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $entity,
        ]);
        $entity = $this->denormalizer->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $tmpContext);

        return $entity;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        if (null === $this->denormalizer) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf('The nested denormalizer needs to be set to allow "%s()" '
                    . 'to be used.', __METHOD__));
        }

        $repository = $this->getRepository($type);
        // Check that it s an Entity of our App and a Repository exist for it
        // Also only use the denormalizer if an ID is set to load from the Repository.
        return strpos($type, 'App\\Entity\\') === 0 && !is_null($repository) && (is_numeric($data) || is_string($data)
                || (is_array($data) && isset($data['id'])));
    }

    protected function getDoctrine(): ManagerRegistry
    {
        return $this->doctrine;
    }

    protected function setDoctrine(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): void
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    protected function getRepository(string $class): ?ObjectRepository
    {
        $result = null;
        try {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass($class);
            if (!is_null($entityManager)) {
                $result = $entityManager->getRepository($class);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            // Manager could not be resolved
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Example serializer definitions of the entities:

```
App\Entity\Group:
    attributes:
        id:
            groups: ['group:read']
        name:
            groups: ['group:read', 'group:write']

App\Entity\Account:
    attributes:
        id:
            groups: ['account:read']
        name:
            groups: ['account:read', 'account:write']
        branchGroups:
            groups: ['account:read', 'account:write']
            max_depth: 1
```

The entities would look like the following:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class Account
{
    protected $id;

    protected $name;

    protected $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addGroup(BranchGroup $group)
    {
        $this->groups->add($group);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGroup(Group $Group)
    {
        $this->groups->removeElement($group);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }

    public function setGroups(iterable $groups)
    {
        $this->groups->clear();
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $this->addGroup($group);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

namespace App\Entity;

class Group
{
    private $id;

    protected $name = '';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Creating/Updating an Account with an existing Group would then look like this:

```
$entity = $this->fetchEntityToUpdate();
jsonData = json_encode([
    'name' => 'newAccountName',
    'groups' => [
        [
           'id' => 1
        ]
    ]
]);
$context = [
    'groups' => ['account:write'],
    AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $entity,
];
$entity = $serializer->deserialize($jsonData, Account::class, 'json', $context);
```

This would now only add/remove the `Group` from the `Account`. If I now want to additionally update the related `Group` object I could just add the additional serialization group `group:write` into the serialization context.

Hope this helps someone who stumbles upon this.

Comment: underrated solution. Code is a bit bloated but give all the ingredients needed for a Denormalizer that won't break the default Serializer behavior

Answer (score 1):

What the Symfony documentation calls "[Recursive Denormalization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety)", starting from version 3.3, enables you to denormalize associated objects and their properties, and will specifically resolve the type error mentioned in the question.

But **this does not make the objects managed by Doctrine!**
This means that associations that have not been normalized will be `null` and will not be automatically fetched from the database.
This method may be suitable for you if what you want is a snapshot of the data at the time of serialization.
If you need the objects to be managed, you have to fetch or merge them with the `EntityManager`.
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295246/5845942) will denormalize identifiers into their corresponding managed entities by fetching them from the database.
Of course, you have to keep in mind that *the normalized data may not correspond to the current state of the database*. IDs may have changed or been deleted, etc.

In order for Symfony to find the property types of the serialized objects, it needs to use the PropertyInfo component, which, as @slk500 stated in his answer, has to be activated in the [framework configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#property-access).

So, if you are using the full framework, all you need to do in order to deserialize nested json objects is this:

1.Enable the serializer and the property info components in config.yml:

```
framework:
    #...
    serializer: { enabled: true }
    property_info: { enabled: true }
```

2. Then [inject the serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-the-serializer-service) wherever you need it:

```php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(SerializerInterface $serializer, Request $request)
    {
        $document = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'AppBundle\Entity\Document', 'json');
        // ...
    }
}
```

The default features of these components were enough for my needs.
Autowiring takes care of the basic service declaration, so unless you need specific normalizers, you don't even have to edit the `services.yml` configuration file.
Depending on your use cases, you may have to enable specific features.
Check the Serializer and PropertyInfo documentation for (hopefully) more specific use cases.

Comment: Hi, doesn't work for me. Doctrine's ArrayCollection are deserialized as arrays, and the entities they contain are also rendered as arrays. SF 4+, serializer factory: `new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer(new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader())), null, null, new ReflectionExtractor())], [new JsonEncoder()]))`

Comment: Do you have a working example with the standalone serializer component?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JMS Serializer, you can use this code and the serializer will search for relation in database.

services.yml

```
services:
    app.jms_doctrine_object_constructor:
        class: AppBundle\Services\JMSDoctrineObjectConstructor
        arguments: ['@doctrine', '@jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor']

    jms_serializer.object_constructor:
        alias: app.jms_doctrine_object_constructor
        public: false
```

AppBundle\Services\JMSDoctrineObjectConstructor.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\VisitorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Construction\ObjectConstructorInterface;

/**
 * Doctrine object constructor for new (or existing) objects during deserialization.
 */
class JMSDoctrineObjectConstructor implements ObjectConstructorInterface
{
    private $managerRegistry;
    private $fallbackConstructor;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry Manager registry
     * @param ObjectConstructorInterface $fallbackConstructor Fallback object constructor
     */
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, ObjectConstructorInterface $fallbackConstructor)
    {
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
        $this->fallbackConstructor = $fallbackConstructor;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function construct(VisitorInterface $visitor, ClassMetadata $metadata, $data, array $type, DeserializationContext $context)
    {
        // Locate possible ObjectManager
        $objectManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManagerForClass($metadata->name);

        if (!$objectManager) {
            // No ObjectManager found, proceed with normal deserialization
            return $this->fallbackConstructor->construct($visitor, $metadata, $data, $type, $context);
        }

        // Locate possible ClassMetadata
        $classMetadataFactory = $objectManager->getMetadataFactory();

        if ($classMetadataFactory->isTransient($metadata->name)) {
            // No ClassMetadata found, proceed with normal deserialization
            return $this->fallbackConstructor->construct($visitor, $metadata, $data, $type, $context);
        }

        // Managed entity, check for proxy load
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            // Single identifier, load proxy
            return $objectManager->getReference($metadata->name, $data);
        }

        // Fallback to default constructor if missing identifier(s)
        $classMetadata = $objectManager->getClassMetadata($metadata->name);
        $identifierList = array();

        foreach ($classMetadata->getIdentifierFieldNames() as $name) {
            if (!array_key_exists($name, $data)) {
                return $this->fallbackConstructor->construct($visitor, $metadata, $data, $type, $context);
            }

            $identifierList[$name] = $data[$name];
        }

        // Entity update, load it from database

        if (array_key_exists('id', $identifierList) && $identifierList['id']) {
            $object = $objectManager->find($metadata->name, $identifierList);
        } else {
            $object = new $metadata->name;
        }

        $objectManager->initializeObject($object);

        return $object;
    }
}
```