# Symfony2 (deserialize): update entity (with association) with json

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I got the serializer in Symfony working, i can GET and POST json with the EntityController. I have an edit form where an existing object/entity can be edited and saved. When the edited object gets posted (as a json object) the json objects gets deserialized, persisted and flushed tot the database. So far so good, at least as long as i dont post associated (ManyToMany) entities.

I have two entities (with a ManyToMany association):

1. Object
2. Element

This works (see also the jsonEditAction in the controller(posted below)):

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "object 1"
}
```

**My question is: How can i edit the object with associated entities in the json, like this:**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "object 1",
    "elements": {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "2"
    }
}
```

When i post the above json i get the following notice from Symfony:

> "message": "Expected argument of type \"AppBundle\Entity\Element\", \"integer\" given",
>                       "class": "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException",

For further information; this is the editAction where the Json is posted to:

```
public function jsonEditAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $serializer = $this->initSerializer();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $object = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Object')->findOneById($id);

    $data = $request->getContent();

    $serializer->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\Object', 'json', array('object_to_populate' => $object));

    try {
        $em->persist($object);
        $em->flush();

        $view = $this->view($object, 200)
                ->setTemplate("object/json.html.twig");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $view = $this->view('Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n", 500)
                ->setTemplate("object/json.html.twig");
    }

    return $this->handleView($view);
}

private function initSerializer() {
    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    return $serializer;
}   `
```

Should i walk to the array with elements and find them one by one and then add them to the 'object' entity? Or is there a 'build-in' solution in the serializer that i missed/ didn't see?

**UPDATE**:
Also the JSON like suggested by Alexey didn't work:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Object 2c",
    "elements": [{
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2
    }]
}
```

**UPDATE**:
My question is a duplicate of:
[Deserialize an entity with a relationship with Symfony Serializer Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741197/deserialize-an-entity-with-a-relationship-with-symfony-serializer-component)
There is a pull request created and will be merged in Symfony 3.2...

Comment: May be your are looking for Symfony [Data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: But as long as serializer is concerned, It should handle transformer implicitly, I used [JMSSerializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) with [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html). But I never faced any such issue. That is because, even the data were being submitted in clean JSON, I always used a form type to handle the post data.

Comment: @Jeet: can you show me an example of your handler?

Comment: There is no handler as such, `FOSRestBundle` handles that with providing events to overwrite. I would suggest, use of `form type` to capture entity association related data. The form will transform data automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad JSON, Symfony says you the same.

A good JSON can look like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "object 1",
    "elements": [
        {"id": "254", "name": "element 254"},
        {"id": "301", "name": "element 301"}
    ]
}
```

Symfony tries to deserialize an `Element` object from `"1"` and `"2"` in your original JSON and fails.

Comment: Hi Alexey, i posted an json like above but i still get the same error