# Simple REST with Symfony Serializer with Doctrine ORM, de-normalization not supported?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, json-deserialization

I have a question / request for ideas regarding the [deserialization of Json](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) in a standard Symfony 4.2 environment.

Think of the following two entities **Post** and **Author**.
Every **Post** has exactly **1 Author** (unidirectional ManyToOne Association).

**Post Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Post
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned": true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=50)
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText(): string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $text
     */
    public function setText(string $text): void
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * @return Author
     */
    public function getAuthor(): Author
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * @param Author $author
     */
    public function setAuthor(Author $author): void
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

}
```

**Author Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Author
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned": true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

Now let's create a simple **Controller** which allows to **GET** and **POST** posts:

```
class SimpleController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/fapi/post/{id}", methods={"GET", "HEAD"})
     * @param int                 $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getEntityAction($id)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $post = $em->getRepository(Post::class)->find($id);

        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $serializedPost = $serializer->serialize($post, 'json');

        return new Response($serializedPost);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/fapi/post", methods={"POST"})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postEntityAction(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->getContent();

        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $post = $serializer->deserialize($data, Post::class, 'json');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response(''); // return newly created Post

    }

}
```

Let's assume there's already Post (id: 1) existing in the data base. We fetch it with *GET /fapi/post/1*. This is the result:

```
{"id":1,"text":"Hello World!","author":{"id":1,"name":"Huber"}}
```

This is perfectly fine, Symfony's ObjectNormalizer takes care for normalization of the Post object and includes the Author object as well into the result.

Now let's try to create a new post with an already existing Author with *POST /fapi/post*:

```
{"id":null,"text":"Hello Universe!","author":{"id":1,"name":"Huber"}}
```

Now we receive an error by Symfony:

> NotNormalizableValueException: The type of the \"id\" attribute for class \"App\Entity\Post\" must be one of \"int\" (\"NULL\" given)

I appreciate the error and understand why it's happening, but isn't there any built-in way of Symfony Serialization to make sure that auto-generated values (by ORM, by constructor like UUID) are not taken into consideration in this "standard case".

Solutions that I am aware of:

1. not sending *id* at all with the request (but as per my understanding of REST full representation of objects should be exchanged)
2. using GetSetMethodNormalizer instead of ObjectNormalizer (as there is not Setter for *id* that works but has several other flaws).
3. excluding *id* from denormalization context (e.g. by 'ignored_attributes')
4. creating custom Normalizer to take care of this situation

For now let's try to change from ObjectNormalizer to GetSetMethodNormalizer to overcome our error and try again to POST.

Now we get another error:

> FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Post::setAuthor() must be an instance of App\Entity\Author, array given

As per the documentation of GetSetMethodNormalizer no further normalization happens when setting the values in denormalization.

So again I appreciate the error and understand what's happening.

**API Platform** takes care of these issues with a custom [denormalization system](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#denormalization)

I understand and appreciate that Symfony and Doctrine are two different packages, **but** as they are combined so often (and indeed usually play wonderful together):

Is there any built-in or known way in Symfony Serialization which basically allows me in the above 'standard cases' to achieve that this chain runs without errors and without customized implementation of Normalizers or others?

Database => Doctrine ORM => Symfony GET object => json => POST same json => Symfony => Doctrine ORM => Database

**P.S.: Another little example:**

GET /fapi/post/1 only delivers

```
{"id":1,"text":"Hello World!","author":{"id":1,"name":"Huber"}}
```

because the ManyToOne Assocation is fetched EAGER, if default LAZY is set then it becomes:

```
{"id":1,"text":"Hello World!","author":{"id":1,"name":"Huber","__initializer__":null,"__cloner__":null,"__isInitialized__":true}}
```

because the ObjectNormalizer serializes the Doctrine Proxy object.

P.P.S: I am aware of [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) and used it a lot but I totally like and support Symfony in having its "own" Serializer Component.

Comment: I don't get why you send `"id":null`, because the *entity* can't have an id with a value null (the object might though).  your proxy objection serialization is another matter though.

Comment: thanks @Jakumi, I get your point. Still I am talking a bit broader in terms of Symfony Serializer supporting Doctrine Entities.

Comment: I would suggest using the deserialize on existing objects like https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object and keeping different routes for creation and updating entities (as it is supposed to be btw). however, the underlying problem is that you somehow have to work out how to handle sub-entities. I don't see how this should be part of the independent symfony serializer, when it is quite doctrine-specific. I hope you get where I'm going with this, it's not the responsibility of the (de)serializer to magically guess the right object.

Comment: if you add some callbacks for certain objects to actually create references (doctrine has this possibly relevant functionality) when only an id is provided, and to create the entity when not. but it's complicated if mixed. I would advise against updating multiple entities of different kind at the same time.

Comment: @Jakumi I understand and as you've seen, I am talking about entities (not interested e.g. in creating a new author with a post etc.) - and yes, it shouldnt be standard behaviour, but the same way Serializer uses e.g. Metadata to normalize why couldn't and perhaps even shouldn't a DoctrineNormalizer handling Doctrine objects and assocs e.g.? See what I am trying to say?

Comment: yeah, I totally get you. related and possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741197/deserialize-an-entity-with-a-relationship-with-symfony-serializer-component (one of the later answers provides a custom normalizer ...)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `nullable=true` solved the error for me. And no changes in the DB mapping were detected either after adding it. So I guess it is perfectly safe.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $id;
```